# Is it possible to save/export results of website audit from Webkit Developer Tools Audit panel?

Tags: testing, webkit, google-chrome-devtools, web-deployment, performance-testing

As stated above, is it possible - whether using some of chrome://chrome-urls/ or maybe some hidden experimental browser features?
I need to perform series of website performance audits and data from results must be available for me, for further analysis.

Although Firefox's built-in dev tools Audit tool allows me to import results, the tool itself lacks the built-in hints system like webkit dev tools have - the result data is raw.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can run an audit from Chrome's dev tools, and export a performance report from the tab 'Audits'

You can choose whether to simulate a mobile device or a desktop.
Run the audit then click the download button in the top left corner of the window.